# Parsing out time-of-day from a date to a separate column

Tags: datetime, openoffice-calc

I have, per cell, a date value in the format `2013-01-05 11:21`.

Is there a way to separate the time of day (ie 11:21) and put it in a new column, without having to manually cut and paste?

I have a lot of date values in one column, and I want to separate the time-of-day portion of these dates into a new adjacent column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - the [**`TIMEVALUE`**](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Calc:_TIMEVALUE_function) function should do this. You may need to format the result cells (in my examle: `B1:B8`) as time values. Using cell formatting, you can set the output to a `hh:mm` syntax, too.

[image: TIMEVALUE example]